# Mutual fund historic prices, seen @ Google and Yahoo, don't match my activity

Tags: investing, mutual-funds, vanguard, yahoo-finance, google-finance

I'd like to understand, how should I interpret the `VFIAX` mutual fund historic prices, which can be found @ [Google Finance](https://www.google.com/finance/quote/VFIAX:MUTF?window=6M) and @ [Yahoo!Finance](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/VFIAX/history/). For example, both these sites show the `VFIAX` closing price `$428.91` on 12/21/2021. However when I look at my account history @ Vanguard, I see that I've purchased a piece of this fund @ `$421.39` on this date.

Why this discrepancy? Is some price adjustment involved here? If yes, then how they calculate the adjusted price?

Comment: Please post two screenshots for future reference. One for Google Finance, and another for Yahoo Finance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

VFIAX closed at 421.39 on 12/20/2021 (both Google and Yahoo show this). I suspect that Vanguard filled your order on the 20th, not the 21st. It's possible that the funds were *settled* the next day - you'd have to ask Vanguard.

Comment: Oh, right! The Vanguard shows the price on the date of the order, but the transaction date (shown in the activity list) is typically one day later, and might be even three of four days later (weekend, holidays)

Comment: @HEKTO: Your confirmation slip (Vanguard provides these in PDF format) definitely will show both the fill date (when the price locked in) and the settlement date (when the money moved and ownership of the shares transferred).